# Testing on missing properties in Firebase -> Database -> Rules

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

In my Firebase -> Database -> Rules editor, I have a match rule for the `write` op on a course that tests if the `status` property is either:

1. Undefined, meaning the property is simply missing from the model props, or
2. Set, with the value 'draft' or 'completed'

To capture this, I wrote the following:

```
match /courses/{courseId} {
  allow write: if (resource.data.status == 'undefined' ||
                   resource.data.status != 'completed');
}
```

That is, a `write` is allowed if the course has no `status` property, or has the property not equal to 'completed'. 
There is no problem with the second part of the condition, The problem is that the first part always causes the typical *ERROR FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions*.

I tried each of the following flavours for the first part, but with no success:

```
resource.data.status == null
resource.data.status == undefined
resource.data.status == 'undefined'
typeof(resource.data.status) == undefined
typeof(resource.data.status) == 'undefined'
```

And, the `===` is simply not syntactically valid in the editor. Any idea how to test against missing properties and get a proper true/false value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently needed this in a project and came up with this function:

```
function isNotExisting(request, resource, key) {
  return !(key in request.resource.data) && (!exists(resource) || !(key in resource.data));
}
```

The main trick is using `key in resource.data` or `key in request.resource.data`, which checks whether the given key exists in the document after or before the operation.

Comment: Makes sense as soon as I read your answer! Re-writing the troublesome part as `!('status' in resource.data)` did it for me! Thanks Frank :-)